# I want get userid value from a private object

Tags: php, moodle

I want to get the userid from:

```
["userid":"course_modinfo":private]=>
    string(1) "5"
```

Here value from moodle $mod in cm info variable, I have tried `var_dump($mod->userid);` but it returns nothing.

```
object(cm_info)#355 (40) {
  ["modinfo":"cm_info":private]=>
  object(course_modinfo)#339 (7) {
    ["course":"course_modinfo":private]=>
    object(stdClass)#354 (33) {
....
     ["userid":"course_modinfo":private]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["sections":"course_modinfo":private]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the global variable:

```
$USER->id
```

Check this out [How to get user id of current user in moodle?](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=187465)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `get_user_id()` function as follows.

```
$mod->get_user_id();
```